# Datatables server-side processing Django

Tags: python, django, datatables

I am trying to get datatables server-side processing to work with a Django backend. I have the following code:

views.py to load HTML:

```
def clients(request):

    path = '/path/to/csv/file.csv' 
    date_time = os.path.getmtime(path)
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date_time)

    html_template = loader.get_template( 'XXXX/clients.html' )
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render({"date":date,},request))
```

HTML table code:

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped">
  <thead style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <tr>
    <th>Network</th>
    <th>Description</th>

    <th>IP</th>
    <th>Mac</th>
    <th>Manufacturer</th>
    <th>Operating system</th>
    <th>Conntect to device</th>
    <th>VLAN</th>
    <th>Switchport</th>
        <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody style="white-space: nowrap;">

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript in the same HTML file as the table code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#table").DataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"scrollX":true,
"ajax" :{url:'{% url "json_response" %}',dataSrc:"data"},
});
});
</script>
```

views.py to get data from url 'json_response':

```
def json_response(request):

    draw = int(request.GET.get('draw'))
    length = int(request.GET.get('length'))
    start = int(request.GET.get('start'))
    substring = str(request.GET.get('search[value]'))
    
    if start == 0:
        start == 0
    else:
        length = start + length
        
    path = '/XX/XX/XXX/XXX.csv'
    clients = pd.read_csv(path)
    recordsTotal=len(clients) 
    clients = clients.rename(columns={"Client description":"client_descr","Client IP":"client_ip","Client MAC":"client_mac","Client Manufacturer":"client_man","Client OS":"client_os","Connected to device":"connected_to",})
    clients['VLAN'] = clients['VLAN'].fillna(0)
    clients['Switchport'] = clients['Switchport'].fillna(0)
    clients['client_man'] = clients['client_man'].fillna('Unknown')
    clients['client_os'] = clients['client_os'].fillna('Unknown')
    clients = clients.astype({"VLAN":int})
    clients = clients.astype({"Switchport":str})
    clients = clients.fillna('None')
    clients = clients.iloc[start:length]
    clients = clients.values.tolist()

    page = 1
    per_page = 25

    
    response = {
    "draw":draw,
    "recordsTotal": recordsTotal,
    "recordsFiltered":recordsTotal,
    "data":clients,
    }
    
    clients = JsonResponse(response,safe=False)
    return clients
```

With this code the paging is working.

The only issues I got is the search and sorting functions. And if possible I would also like to have to buttons (pdf,csv,excel, etc...)

Can someone help me to configure the search, sort and maybe the buttons function?

Comment: "_The only issues I got is the search and sorting functions_" - You are already accessing `search[value]` - is that not providing the global search term for you to use? (You should also use `search[regex]` so you know how to interpret the search term.) Similarly, for sorting, you need to use `order[i][column]` and `order[i][dir]` to get each of the column sort orders (where `i` is an index number). See [sent parameters](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters).

Comment: "_I would also like to have to buttons_" - that's a completely different question. There are _many_ questions and answers on SO already for this. And it's [thoroughly documented](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) on the DataTables web site, with [lots of examples](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/). Be warned: Using export buttons with `serverSide: true` is contradictory. The whole point of server-side processing is to only send one page of data at a time to the browser. Export buttons assume you have sent the entire data set.